# A java program such that one character from the first string is concatenated with one character from the second string from left to right

Tags: java, string

Write a Java program that takes two strings as input from the user . Then the program creates another string 
such that one character from the first string is concatenated with one character from the second string from left to right 
as shown below:

exampl 1:

```
First Input String: Hello Hi

Second input String: World of Mine

Output String: HWeolrllodHoif Mine
```

Comment: What does this have to do with regex?

Comment: This is not a question and we will not do your work for you! You will never learn programming by this way.

Comment: Stop being lazy, stop cheating, and do your own homework.

Comment: Totally agree, stop being lazy and start to think or you'll never learn anything.

Comment: I m not getting how to solve it..please help me

Comment: @alisha it would be better to learn more about String operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution expanding on your own code (with explanations). Please try to understand the code, before using it in your homework.

```
public static String concateAndAppend(String data1, String data2) {
    char[] str1 = data1.toCharArray();
    char[] str2 = data2.toCharArray();
    String result = "";

    //we must iterate to the length of the smaller string
    //if you don't calculate the smaller size you might
    //get indexOutOfBounds Exceptions, i.e. you try to access
    //non-existant indexes in the arrays
    int minimum = Math.min(str1.length, str2.length); //calculate minimum between the two array lenghts

    //append the characters on the same index to the result
    //starting with str1 from left
    for (int i = 0; i < minimum; i++) {
        result = result + str1[i] + str2[i];
    }

    //now you must pad the results to include the bigger string
    //since you only iterated minimum index positions.

    //check which string is bigger then append accordingly
    if (str1.length > minimum) {
        result = result + data1.substring(minimum); //substring to only append the part after the minimum index
    } else if (str2.length > minimum) {
        result = result + data2.substring(minimum);//substring to only append the part after the minimum index
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "Hello Hi";
    String s2 = "World of Mine";

    System.out.println(concateAndAppend(s1, s2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the two in a loop:

```
String s1 = "Hello Hi";
String s2 = "World of Mine";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder (s1.size() + s2.size());

int minLength = Math.min (s1.size(), s2.size());
for (int i = 0; i < minLength; ++i) {
    result.append(s1.charAt(i)).append(s2.charAt(i));
}
if (s1.size() > minLength) {
    result.append(s1.substring(minLength));
} else if (s12.size() > minLength) {
    result.append(s2.substring(minLength));
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't just provide a solution for his homework. good one but still not appropriate. you should at least let him try first.

Comment: Thanx for ur answer..m new to java..just beginner...

Comment: public String concateAndAppend(String data1,String data2)
 {
  char[] str1=data1.toCharArray();
  char[] str2=data2.toCharArray();
  String result="";
  for(char ch1:str1)
  {
   result=result+ch1;
   
   for(char ch2:str2)
   {
    result=result+ch2;
    
   }
   
  }
  return result;
 }

Comment: @alisha look at your for, for each char in the first string you append every char from the second. you have to use the same index, append in turn

Comment: can u please improvise this..

Comment: @alisha check my answer, i've expanded on your code. BUT the solution proposed by Mureinik is much 'cleaner' since it uses stringBuilder. Strings are immutable objects so each time you write something like result = result +"something" you create a new string, destroying the old one. This is not very optimal. Stringbuilder works around this.

Comment: I am not getting the substring part..can u please make it more clear to me?

Comment: @alisha `substring` returns the part of the string from the given index to its end. So after iterating over both strings and appending character by character until the end of the shorter one, I take all the characters remaining in the longer one (by `substring`) and append them to the result.